# JumpNote: main type is not specified

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm doing my 1st steps in Android/GoogleApp, and I'm trying to explore the Jumpnote example:
http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/

I was able to import the Android and Appengine projects to eclipse, but encountered the following issue when trying to run the Jumpnote-web part (android runs well).

When running the web part there is an error `Main type is not specified` which AFAIK implied that this project is missing a main function.

Is that indeed the case for jumpnote example and I need to manually add it, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to run Configuration
2. select JumpNoteWeb run configuration
3. You see in the main tab your project name and below it says main class
4. In the main class, put "com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode"
5. it should now run

*When I had this problem I also need to make sure that I put the src.shared folder into my project and had to change my build order so the app engine sdk, gwt sdk, and jre would build first