# .apt_generated which is referenced by classpath does not exist while debugging the sample C2DM project of google appengine project with android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine

While [Customizing the Starter Project](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_add_rpc.html) in App Engine Connected Android Project. I downloaded the source code of the project shown in [Google I/O 2011: Android + App Engine: A Developer's Dream Combination](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U) from http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/. When importing the project into Workspace I see a black star on the Android project( see the pic).
1. What does this black star mean??
[image: black star]

Then when I try to debug it as (Local app engine connected to android). It gives the error 
".apt_generated which is referenced by classpath does not exist" in the pic.

[image: error]

Thanks.

Comment: Following the instructions in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850463/jumpnote-main-type-is-not-specified) question's answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

1 the black star is know as the project/files you are modified that is not updated to your SVN. so it will show the modified files as *.

2 
Delete you bin dir and clean your project and run it once again. It will resolve your error.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to second, that doesn't solve it for me either.